# add an obiee analyses created by a direct databse query to a dashboard with prompt

Tags: obiee

We use OBIEE 11g and I discover that you can create an analyse with a direct databse query. I want to add this analyse in a dashboard and interact with the dashboard prompts. 
is that Possible?

Or how can I add prompts to this analyse?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but you will have to have your dashboard prompt write its values into presentation variables and capture those variables in the WHERE clause of your DDR.